# Javascript to redirect when going from secure to non secure page

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

We have an issue if a customer leaves the shopping cart page and goes back into the main website (to check something before buying, for example). When they leave this https page, any page they navigate to will show https error. Though not ideal, this is not the main problem. When they decide they want to continue with the purchase and they go back to the cart the unsecured message still shows. We were told that javascript code could resolve this issue by redirecting visitors to the appropriate URL as they navigate between secure and non secure pages. Many thanks.

Comment: Are you using a `<base href="http://example.com/" />` tag or are your URL's absolute?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot resolve this issue as SSL protocol happens before JS rendering. 
You should either resolve the HTTPS error or redirect on your server (apache/nginx?) level.